# jQuery Slider - Slide Links outside Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm currently using the slidesjs.com slider and I'm wanting to make it so when I click a link outside the slider it slides to the current slide e.g. click slide one link (#1) and it slides to slide one (#1) within the slider. Here is my coding any help would be much appreciated.

```
$(function(){
            // Set starting slide to 1
            var startSlide = 1;
            // Get slide number if it exists
            if (window.location.hash) {
                startSlide = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
            }
            // Initialize Slides
            $('#passion_slider').slides({
                autoHeight: true,
                // Get the starting slide
                start: startSlide,
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    // Set the slide number as a hash
                    window.location.hash = '#' + current;
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to ready event. Use target var for destination.

```
$(window).click(function(){
  var target="#1";  
  $('a[href='+target+']').click()
})
```

Solution for specific task!!!
Adding click trigger to links for direct showing specific slide:

```
//$('.passionnavigation li a').unbind(); //unbind all events on links
$('.passionnavigation li a').click(function(){
  var targetH = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#passion_slider a[href='+targetH+']').click();
})
```

Comment: The coding only takes you to the first slide.

Comment: Also when i click within the slide it also changes, im just looking for it to change slide once clicked the navigation links outside the slider. if you know a solution to this problem it would be much appreciated dude.

Comment: @Adam set new id in target var. Say more about your page what you want to  achive.
Replace $(window) with $('.mainwrapper') for problem outside slider.

Comment: I'll try tell you a little more about my problem, I'm trying to get the link Passion Radio to make the slider move to slide #0, Shout Out to move to slide #1, Events to slide #2 & Contact us to slide #3 please have a quick look at the link if you need to see what i mean http://www.media21a.co.uk/clientlogin/passionradio/

Comment: I've found this works a treat :) $('.link').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $('#passion_slider .pagination li:eq(' + (link - 1) + ') a').click();
    return false;
});